# Can Premake package a project?

Tags: premake

I have a Premake 5 project that builds a static library (primarily via the `gmake2` or `vs2017` actions). I'd like to create a build target for the release material itself: the library zipped up with some text and header files.

How do I do this with Premake? I tried something like:

```lua
project "thing_export"

    kind "Utility"

    os.mkdir "Release"
    -- etc
```

...but of course the `os...` functions are executed when Premake runs, they don't end up in the build files.

I also tried using [custom build commands](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Custom-Build-Commands):

```lua
project "thing_export"

    kind "Utility"

    buildmessage "Creating release"
    buildcommands { "{copy} README.md '%{prj.location}'" }
    buildoutputs { "'%{prj.location}/README.md'" }
```

The makefile generated by the `gmake` or `gmake2` actions is the same as for an empty project. No actions are generated for it.

How can I use Premake to create my releases?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to do, you might be able to make that approach work. What I usually do (and what Premake itself does) is write a Lua script to automate the release packaging, and use [a custom Premake action](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Starting-Your-New-Action) to run it.

Have a look at [Premake's package.lua script](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/blob/master/scripts/package.lua) to see how it automates the packaging. And here is the custom action that calls `package.lua`:

```lua
newaction {
    trigger = "package",
    description = "Creates source and binary packages",
    execute = function ()
        include (path.join(corePath, "scripts/package.lua"))
    end
}
```

Comment: Can you make this depend on other build artefacts eg. the static library?